# Cannot perform network operations within an OnClickListener within an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, multithreading, crash, listener, android-alertdialog

For some reason my application crashes when I start a new Thread inside an OnClickListener of an AlertDialog. I tried using an AsyncTask and that did not work either. Any suggestions please?

Heres my code, thanks in advance.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Perform Operation? ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    //Perform network operations
                }
            });

            thread.start();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Any LogCat @Developer ?

Comment: Also, are you doing any `UI` stuff in your `Thread`?

Comment: public static int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

add this before you do operations

if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
    ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
    }

Comment: Can you post any error message or the code inside `run()`?
And I wouldn't do what @user1920666 said. It's doable, but potential long operations shouldn't be executed in the main thread, and network operations can take a long time.

Comment: @user1920666 - ignoring the problem isn't really a solution

Comment: for these situations, please use Async task to perform any network operation,and then you can update your UI when onPostExecute get called.